# Switch to main activity after 10 Seconds if no touch registered

Tags: android

I am developing survey application on android tablet and I want to make this. When a activity running if you don't touch to screen until 10 second I want to leave main activity automatically how can I do this? I used below code but I got a error.

```
static int x = 0; // must be static

Bundle get_data;
int bas_i;
TextView txt, text2;

// Button secretbtn;

String Type;
int TypeID;
int GrpID;
int id;

int sorusayisi = 0;
int cevaplanan = 0;
boolean hata = false;

int akis_soru_sorusayisi = 0;

String last_Type_inmethod;

Bundle data_gonder;

// Dynamic Buttons

Button btn1;
Button btn2;
Button btn3;
Button btn4;
Button btn5;

private static Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sonraki_olay);

    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10*1000);

    btn1 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    btn2 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    btn3 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    btn4 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    btn5 = new Button(getApplicationContext());

    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    // secretbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.secret_button);
    //
    // secretbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    // secretbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // secretbtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    get_data = getIntent().getExtras();
    bas_i = get_data.getInt("data_sonraki_soru_id");
    // txt.setText(""+i);
    // Log.i("get_data_from_sonraki_Activity", ""+i);

    data_gonder = new Bundle();

    gonder();

}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10 * 1000);
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}

public void run() {
    // start activity here
    Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: What error? Give us log output.

Comment: please add your Log output, I expect you have a context error

Comment: I coming after 10 second to mainActivity if I don't touch screen but When I run again to application it didn't comes next activity it returns mainActivity again

Answer (score 0):

You should not start an Activity from a background thread. You can use an Handler to achieve that:

change the following code:

```
    Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                    getBaseContext().getPackageName());
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    startActivity(i);
```

to:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(
     new Runnable(){
           Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                            getBaseContext().getPackageName());
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            startActivity(i);
     }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by doing the following -

Create a new field in your activity to store the delay:

```
private long delay = 0;
```

In your *onCreate*:

```
    //Check for touches on our main layout
    LinearLayout ll_main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.survey_main_layout);
    ll_main.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //If someone touches, reset our delay
            delay = 0;
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Where you want to start checking the delay put the following:

```
    //Start a thread that will keep count of the time
    new Thread("Listen for touch thread") {
        public void run() {
            //Keep checking until the activity dies
            while(!this.isFinishing()) {
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //Incement the delay
                delay += 50;

                //If our delay in MS is over 10,000
                if (delay >= 10000) {
                    //Create a new intent on our UI Thread and start it!
                    //Change myActivity to the name of your activity!
                    myActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       public void run() {
                           Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                                        getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                            startActivity(i);
                    });
                    return; //Return to end the thread
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

A smart idea if you want to do this every time you go back to this activity is put the

```
new Thread() { ... }.start();
```

code into the *onResume* method, and reset your delay.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is probably because you have stalled the UI Thread for too long, Android does not like that and sends an error to the user because your app is now not responsive (and that is exactly why the UI thread exists).

The proper way is to use a Handler and the postDelayed method:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    startActivity();
                }
            }, 10000);
        }

        private void startActivity() {
            Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                        getBaseContext().getPackageName());
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

Furthermore to do what you want you should set a onClick that cancels the Handler.